# Kendo UI - convert table grid tr rows into individual tables

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui-grid

Below is the HTML code. I need each row for this "GRID" to be displayed as individual table rather than a single table with rows.

### HTML:

```
                                        },
                                        {"field":
                                        "KeyValues.AmountWeight_UnitRef.Value.DisplayName", headerTemplate:GetMLString("AmountWeight_Unit"),editor:lookupEditor
                                        },
                                        {"field":
                                        "KeyValues.AmountVolume_Value.Value", headerTemplate:GetMLString("Amount^$~(volume)"),editor:NumericEditor
                                        , attributes: { "class": "TEAMSNumeric" }

                                        },
                                        {"field":
                                        "KeyValues.AmountVolume_UnitRef.Value.DisplayName", headerTemplate:GetMLString("AmountVolume_Unit"),editor:lookupEditor
                                        },
                                        {"field":
                                        "KeyValues.Comment.Value", headerTemplate:GetMLString("Comment"),editor:TextInlineEditor
                                        },
                                        {"field":
                                        "KeyValues.DocLink.Value", headerTemplate:GetMLString("Doc^$~link"),editor:TextInlineEditor
                                        },

                                    ]' data-bind="source:data.FuelConsDetails.Value, events: { change: gridClick }">                                    
                                </div></br>
```

Js:

Comment: Below is the HTML code. I need each row for this "GRID" to be displayed as individual table rather than a single table with rows.

Comment: <div id='FuelConsDetail_Grid' data-role='grid' data-sortable='true' data-editable='true' data-navigatable= 'true' data-selectable='true' data-columns={"field":
           "KeyValues.FuelTypeRef.Value.DisplayName", headerTemplate:GetMLString("Fuel^$~type"),editor:lookupEditor
           },
           {"field":
           "KeyValues.EquipmentRef.Value.DisplayName", headerTemplate:GetMLString("Equipment"),editor:lookupEditor
           },]' data-bind="source:data.FuelConsDetails.Value, events: { change: gridClick }">         
         </div>

Comment: This is the HTML code. I need each row for this "GRID" to be displayed as individual table rather than a single table with rows.

Comment: PLZ HELP ME AS IT'S VERY URGENT.

Comment: Please don't put your code into the comments. Edit it into the question where it can be properly formatted.

Comment: Please read [this post on why it's not appropriate to use "it's very urgent" here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 0):

You can use row template to customise rows of the grid to look like grid. Use below url for sample.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/rowtemplate